# Cannot add foreign key constraint - Laravel Entrust

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, entrust

I really don't know what is wrong, but I cannot add foreign key constraint with this query.

```
alter table `__acc_role_user` add constraint `__acc_role_user_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `__acc_accounts` (`account_id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
```

How I'm creating the accounts table?

```
    Schema::create('__acc_accounts', function($table)
    {
        $table->integer('account_id')->increments();
        $table->integer('points')->default(0);

        $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

And then Entrust Migration (only the problematic section is below):

```
    Schema::create('__acc_role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('account_id')->on('__acc_accounts')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('__acc_roles')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

Comment: Have you added index to foreign key?

Comment: $table->integer('account_id')->increments(); should be unsigned()

Comment: Yes, I added the index to foreign key.

When I change the $table->integer('account_id')->increments(); to unsigned() then I get the same error but for __acc_accounts table: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sintax is better:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('__acc_accounts', function($table)
    {
        $table->integer('account_id')->increments();
        $table->integer('points')->default(0);
    });

    Schema::table('__acc_accounts', function(Blueprint $table)
{
        $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('__acc_accounts');
}
```

**And very important!** In your migration order must be: first create the table 'accounts' and after '__acc_accounts'.

> Tables with foreign keys should be created after the tables they reference to have been created.

This http://blog.kongnir.com/2015/03/08/laravel-order-of-migrations-with-foreign-keys/ can help you tu understand this.